# Typecasting an array of enums as [Any]

Tags: swift

When I try to pass an array of enums to a method which accepts `[Any]`, I get a warning telling me "'EnumType' not identical to 'Any'". There is no warning if I pass `EnumType` or `[EnumType]` to a method with a parameter of type `Any`. Can someone shed some light as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a type as a parameter into a function that takes an `Any`, the compiler silently does a conversion for you – if you have `f(a: Any)` and you call `f(x)`, it's kind of like the compiler writing `f(x as Any)` for you.

But to create an array is a bit more complicated, involving iterating over the whole array converting the contents one by one, and the compiler doesn't do that automatically.

Happily it's easy to do by hand:

```
// some function that just takes an array of Any and prints them
func takeAnys(anys: [Any]) {
    ",".join(anys.map(toString)) 
}

let ints: [Int] = [1,2,3]

// won't compile
takeAnys(ints)

// this iterates over each entry and converts it to Any,
// returning a new array of them
takeAnys(ints.map { $0 as Any })
```

Note, passing an `[EnumType]` into a function that takes an `Any` is a bit different to passing an array into a function that takes an `[Any]`.  The former works because `Any` can hold anything, including an array, so you you get `[EnumType] as Any` which is fine.  But your function wants an *array* of `Any`, that is, an array with the contents converted to `Any`, rather than an array that has itself been converted to an `Any`.

It's worth noting that this feature does work with classes – if you have an array of subclasses, you *can* pass it into a function that takes an array of superclasses.  But this is specific to reference types, you can't get the same behavior with enums or structs (or protocols of them, which is what `Any` is).